# Request is not giving response if i use it with await inside a try block?

Tags: node.js, request, okta

I have a piece of code where I am trying to get the response from Okta to a variable and return it to the calling service.

I am trying to use async also along with this. But this is keep getting failed like response from the post request is never coming to the try block. How can I achive this?

```
exports.oktaLogin = async function (request) {
    //const transaction = await sequelizedb.transaction();
    logger.info('UserServices.oktaLogin',request);
    let headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    let username = request.username;
    let password = request.password;
    let dataString = "{\"username\": \""+username+"\", \"password\": \""+password+"\", \"options\": { \"multiOptionalFactorEnroll\": true, \"warnBeforePasswordExpired\": true } }";
    //console.log(dataString);
    options = {
        url: constants.OKTA_URL,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: dataString
    };

    function callback(error, response, body) {
        //console.log('Called Call back');
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('Inside call back');
            console.log(body);
            if(body){
                return { success: true, user: body };
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return { success: false, error: 'No User Found' };
        }
    }
    try {
        let some = await reqcall(options, callback);
        console.log('--------------------------')
        console.log(some);
    } catch (error) {
        return { success: false, error: 'No User Found' };
    }
```

};

How do I make the call back to work with async?

Also is there a possibility to use this With axios?

Comment: what is reqcall here?

Comment: same As request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `axios`, I would write something like

```js
const axios = require('axios');

exports.oktaLogin = async (req) => {
    const { username, password } = req;
    const payload = {
        username, password,
        options: { multiOptionalFactorEnroll: true, warnBeforePasswordExpired: true }
    };

    try {
        const res = await axios.post(constants.OKTA_URL, payload);
        return {
            success: true,
            user: res.data
        };
    } catch (err) {
        return {
            success: false,
            error: 'No User Found',
            message: err.message
        };
    }
};
```

that matchs what you have, but I would do a bit more, for example, I would not rely on `success` but would send back an error for example

```js
const axios = require('axios');

exports.oktaLogin = async (username, password) => {
    const payload = {
        username, password,
        options: { multiOptionalFactorEnroll: true, warnBeforePasswordExpired: true }
    };

    return await axios.post(constants.OKTA_URL, payload);
};
```

the function will now return what it should, and you know exactly what parameters such function needs (username and password, and not the ExpressJs full request object as you don't need and looking at the function signature it's hard to understand what you will need that object to have)

then I'd use as

```js
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req;

    if (!isUsernameValid(username) || !isPasswordValid(username)) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid input' });
    }

    try {
        const login = await oktaLogin(username, password);
        res.json({
            user: login.data
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: err.message });
    }
});
```

where, just as an example

```js
const isPasswordValid = password => password.length > 8;
const isUsernameValid = username => username.length > 3;
```

---

you could read a bit more about `axios` and create your own javascript file to test what it returns and what it gets, a simple file with

```js
const axios = require('axios');
(async() => {

    const HOST = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
    const api = axios.create({
        baseURL: HOST
    });

    // get first TODO
    let res = await api.get('/todos/1');
    console.log(res.status, JSON.stringify(res.data, null, 2));

    // create new TODO
    res = await api.post('/todos', {
        title: 'test title',
        body: 'test body'
    });
    const newId = res.data.id;
    console.log(res.status, JSON.stringify(res.data, null, 2));

    // delete last todo
    res = await api.delete(`/todos/${newId}`);
    console.log(res.status, JSON.stringify(res.data, null, 2));
})();
```

and try other calls, use a REST service for example, like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ so you can use other HTTP verbs

and run as `node ./index.js` (if the new file is `index.js`

---

[image]